# Webbrowser Silverlight Error HRESULT: 0xC00CEE21

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010

Is impossible insert the web browser in silverlight web, return error HRESULT: 0xC00CEE21..
i have updated silverlight 4, web and sdk but null..

Comment: Can you please provide more information (and possibly add the actual question you want answered)?

Comment: Any information? You have made a statement about a malfunction with very little detail provided, but have asked no question. Please re-read your own "question" objectively and decide what you want from it.

Comment: i have use the visual studio 2010, for creating a silverlight application web..inserted a textbox, one button and webrowser but doesn't it insert and return error. The application is for silverlight 4

Answer (score 0):

Remark from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser%28v=vs.95%29.aspx): The WebBrowser control is intended for use in Silverlight applications that run outside the browser only.

Comment: True, but that is not the cause of the design-time issue he is getting. You should be able to drop the WebBrowser control into a form, it will just show up blank at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

It should normally come up like this:

[image: Example of inserted browser]

The error on insertion is an indication that your SDK/Tools install is broken. I suggest you reinstall Silverlight and the Silverlight Tool 4 For VS2010 SDK.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838244%28v=VS.95%29.aspx

Hopefully it will work again after reinstalling.

*Please note you can only use the WebBrowser control in OOB mode.*

Comment: OOB = "Out Of Browser" mode. That is a special option of running Silverlight applications that run more like a desktop app once installed (with raised security options and Web Browser control).